# Does Einstein’s general theory of relativity contain a flaw?

Tags: general-relativity, geometry

Einstein's **general theory of relativity** is based on *non-Euclidean* geometry, namely on the geometry created by **Riemann**. If *Riemannian geometry* contains a flaw, logically the *general theory of relativity* also contains that flaw. Does Riemann's theory contain a flaw?

.

The geometry Einstein adopted was devised by others: it is a geometry based on Euclid's axioms, as modified by (firstly) Hilbert and (secondly) Riemann.

Euclid originally defined a line as: *drawn from one point to any other, and extended in a straight line*. Hilbert modified this: proposing that *two points determine a line, and determine it completely* (Hilbert's axiom 1.2), defining coordinate lines.

Hilbert produced a set of theorems (based on axioms which were a mix of his own modifications of Euclid's axioms, and of modifications of Euclid's work by others), which were widely accepted, and which we treat as the modern definition of *Euclidean geometry*.

.

However, there were dissenters from that general acceptance. Riemann for one: who created his own geometry, by adopting Hilbert's first 29 theorems, but substituting theorems of his own for the remainder of Hilbert's work (i.e. rejecting Hilbert's theorems from Theorem 30 onwards).

And although Riemann claimed to have adopted the first 29 of Hilbert's theorems in full, he actually modified Hilbert's aforementioned axiom 1.2 (an axiom on which Hilbert's Theorem 8 depends). Riemann redefined that axiom (which Hilbert had *already* modified from Euclid's original) as: *every pair of points is in some line, and [..] two different lines cannot contain the same pair of points*.

Yet Riemann claimed (and Einstein was thereby misled) that Euclidian and Riemannian geometry are *identical* as regards their first 29 theorems.

Actually, Riemannian geometry violates Hilbert's Theorem 8, because Riemann redefined (see above) one of the axioms upon which that theorem depends. Therefore Riemann's geometry actually differs from Euclidean geometry even within the 29 theorems common to both systems.

Crucially, the violation is in Theorem 8: a very early link in Hilbert's reasoning. Theorems 9 to 29 depend upon Theorem 8. Thus the difference in that early link in the chain propogates through the following 20 links. Riemann's modification of Theorem 8 leaves the two systems with only seven theorems in common, rather than (as Einstein had *wrongly* assumed) twenty nine. And those 29 are also the foundation for all of Riemann's own theorems.

Riemannian geometry becomes self-contradictory from Theorem 30, because it is based on Hilbert's logic, developed by Hilbert in 29 logical steps in his Theorems 1 through 29, but Riemann's system subverts that logic at step 8.

Under Riemann's version of axiom 1.2, when coordinates are added to the geometry there is a contradiction with Riemann's own theorems: the basis of the contradiction being that Riemann postulates that (a) there are *no parallels*, but also that (b) *two straight lines cannot enclose a space*.

.

That is how the contradiction was expressed to me, a non-physicist.

In the light of Riemann's modification of Hilbert's Theorem 8, does Riemann's version of Axiom 1.2 give rise to a contradiction in Riemann's system (for example, by creating a contradiction with Riemann's Theorem 30 et seq), for the reasons I've outlined?

Secondly, given that Riemannian geometry is a key element underpinning Einstein's general theory of relativity, what is the significance of that contradiction for the theory of relativity?

Comment: Probably more adequate for http://math.stackexchange.com/ But the short answer is no, there are no known problems with Riemannian geometry, there are open questions though. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51068/open-questions-in-riemannian-geometry. I could not follow your argument though.

Comment: The geometry in general relativity is pseudo-Riemannian.

Comment: IMO, this is for mathSE and I would d/v as not being useful to physics until some  mathematical verification ( or otherwise) is produced. Sorry, no offence intended in the d/v, I do appreciate that you have put thought into your post.

Comment: @TáMéCeart Since it's about the use of differential geometry in general relativity, and also about differential geometry itself, it can be in either SE. However, it is an unclear question and the wording itself reflects that the OP does not have knowledge of differential geometry. I am closing as unclear.

Comment: This question is very long and difficult to follow, would it be possible to reword it in 10 lines?

Comment: As requested, I have re-edited my original post to provide, hopefully, clarification.

Answer (score 3):

> Given that Riemannian geometry is a key element underpinning Einstein's general theory of relativity, what is the significance to  GR.

Please understand that my physics is self taught and unfortunately my math skills are even worse, so I would be wasting your time tackling the axiomatic underpinnings you outline.

But I think I can say with some confidence hat physics has already answered your question in the negative. We have been testing GR repeatedly over the last 100 years and if there were low energy discrepancies, (mild ST curvature)   due to a mathematical subtlety, it would have appeared by now.

Obviously, I have no idea regarding higher energies, equivalent to regions of "severe"  curvature, if you follow my naive explanation/analogy, such as a black hole but even then, the recent LIGO results regarding gravitational waves would tend to expermentally support the proposition that no flaw exists.

I apologise that I can't put my argument in more sophisticated language.

Comment: Interestingly, it had not previously been explained to me that the geometry might exhibit a distinction between a low-energy and a high-energy state. My principal interest, as a non-expert, is simply in whether GR might be best understood in terms of Hilbert's geometry or Riemann's.

Comment: ahhhh, well I should make it clear that my use of the word energy is intended to mean using $E=mc^2$ to convert mass to energy,  as the source of the amount of curvature. So in that sense the rest mass/energy of Earth is much less than the rest mass /energy of a neutron star. It was just a handy way of including radiation and mass under the same term.  It's not necessarily the same usage as in particle physics, or quantum mechanics, where there are discrete energy states and a clear distinction between low and high energy regimes, such as in a particle accelerator.